# iOS sms html link not updating itself

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

So a rather peculiar issue is occurring. I work for a News company and we have a mobile app. We allow our users to share stories, and we utilize the "sms:&body=..." method of sending a user from html link -> messages app with a pre-populated text. This works fine. The issue that's happening is that, let's say a user clicks our 'Text' link, and they get redirected to the messages app with the pre-populated text filled. But let's say the user doesn't send any text or cancel it, and goes back to our app via the little '<' button in the status bar, and then tries to text another story, the pre-populated text is not updated and still uses the old pre-populated text. Is there any way we can tell messages to update with the new body text?

I have noticed though, if you 'cancel' the text then it works fine.

Here's my current code

`Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri("sms:&body=" + ShareSMSText));`

Comment: Did you double check that `ShareSMSText` has a different value the next time around?

Comment: Alternatively you can have a look at the share plugin that doesn't limit the user to the sms/messages app: https://blog.xamarin.com/simplify-sharing-with-plugins-for-xamarin/

Comment: @der_michael Yes, it's injected on each page view. And has been confirmed to be correct (correct as in, the string is correct) when debugging.